# remove tag event in tag jquery

Tags: jquery, events, tags

I am using [Tags jquery](http://textextjs.com/manual/plugins/tags.html) . I have successfully integrated it for adding tags but I need to perform some action when I remove tag means when I click on cross (x) icon of tag.I am not able to get this event on its documentation.

I tried something like this but not working...

```
$('#textarea').textext()[0].tags().onClick(function(e,tag,value){
        alert(value);
    });
```

Please help me guys...

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no build in event but u can create it by yourself modifying the plugin:

```
//line 411 of texttext.plugin.tags.js
p.onClick = function(e)
    {
        var self   = this,
            core   = self.core(),
            source = $(e.target),
            focus  = 0,
            tag
            ;

        if(source.is(CSS_DOT_TAGS))
        {
            focus = 1;
        }
        else if(source.is(CSS_DOT_REMOVE))
        {
                    tag = source.parents(CSS_DOT_TAG + ':first');
            self.removeTag(source.parents(CSS_DOT_TAG + ':first'));
            focus = 1;
                    // here is modification
                    self.trigger('tagRemove',tag, tag.data(CSS_TAG));
                    // modification end
        }
        else if(source.is(CSS_DOT_LABEL))
        {
            tag = source.parents(CSS_DOT_TAG + ':first');
            self.trigger(EVENT_TAG_CLICK, tag, tag.data(CSS_TAG), tagClickCallback);
        }

        //the rest of code in the plugin
    };
```

and use it like:

```
$('#textarea')
    .textext({ plugins: 'tags' })
    .bind('tagRemove', function(e,tag,value)
    {
        alert('tagRemoved');
    })
;
```

Comment: it is not working dude..I copied paste your code from line 411.. but after it showing me error SyntaxError: syntax error
 

[...]

 
jquery.js (line 2, col 12)
TypeError: $(...).textext is not a function
 

.textext({ plugins: 'tags' })

Comment: Well u need to use only one line, which I marked as "//here is modification", the rest was to visually see where to place it in the code

Comment: actually I was using it's previous version file and I think code may be little different from new version so I downloaded new file and using it's textext.plugin.tags.js file and this is my code $('#textarea').textext({ plugins: 'tags' }); but error is coming on line no 23 of js file TypeError: $.fn.textext is undefined
 

$.fn.textext.TextExtTags = TextExtTags;

Comment: It looks to me that u did not include all js files. Is textext.core.js in place?

Comment: ok i did that now I have included core js,css and tag adding is wrokign perfect but after that I change this line of code self.trigger('tagRemove', tag, tag.data(CSS_TAG), null); at line no 427 and using same code above for using it but giving me error TypeError: tag is undefined
 

self.trigger('tagRemove', tag, tag.data(CSS_TAG), null);

Comment: I did it you forgot one more line to add in modification code tag = source.parents(CSS_DOT_TAG + ':first'); .Anyways you are genius without you it was not possible for me.Thanks for this.I have one more question Actuall I have two fields 'id' and 'email' I want to show 'email' in textarea but in hidden field i need 'id' is it possible??

Comment: I ve modified the answer since tag should not be passed if it is deleted :). Glad it worked for you. As for the next question I am not sure what situation you 're talking about. Perhaps it would be better to create new question with more details?

Comment: no you have done wrobg. actually I need value too. Please check my edited answer of yours. And Please tell me I have initial value e.g $a = "\"abc\""; and in jquery I have written $('#textarea').textext()[0].tags().addTags([<?=$a; ?>]); It is adding value below the textarea and also do not have value in hidden field.

Comment: @BhuvneshGupta I have edited the answer to reflect your suggestions. As for the other things I think its better to ask a new question